# Converting CURL command to Python with requests

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I want to use the requests library in Python to make a POST request.
But the API I'm trying to use uses curl to make the request and I don't know how to convert that.

This is the curl command:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api/recognize?secret_key=abc" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image=@/path/to/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
```

For the moment I'm just using a URL instead of the image itself as a workaround.

Code:

```
params = (
    ('image_url', '2015-BMW-320djpg'),
    ('secret_key', 'abc'),
)

response = requests.post('https://api/recognize_url', params=params)
```

Comment: For reference, https://curl.trillworks.com/ lets you paste a curl request and it transforms it into Requests code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's no "cURL -> Requests" translator, but it should be fairly easy to translate that one request (and requests like it) to use the requests module.

```
files = {'image': open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb')}
params = {'secret_key': 'abc'}
headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, paste your command into [curlconverter.com/python/](https://curlconverter.com/python/) and it will convert it to

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
}

params = {
    'secret_key': 'abc',
}

files = {
    'image': open('/path/to/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api/recognize', params=params, headers=headers, files=files)
```

Then, the `'image': open('/path/to/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg', 'rb'),` line is wrong because the `;type=image/jpeg` is not part of the file path to your image. To correct it, you need to read the [curl documentation for the `-F` flag](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) and the [Requests documentation for the `files=` parameter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) (or just the [Advanced Usage page](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)) to know that you need to change it to

```py
files = {
    'image': ('image.jpg', open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
}
```